# Install vtk toolkit for Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, pip, wget, vtk, python-3.7

I'm setting up a new Windows 10 PC at work. I'm facing issues in trying to install vtk 8.1.2 for Python 3.7.3, which is the only version there is on my PC.

This is what I get trying with pip 19.1.1 and wget:

```
C:\Users\staff>pip install vtk
Collecting vtk
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from 
versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk


C:\Users\staff>wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/55/.../vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
--2019-06-20 08:52:49--  
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/55/.../vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Resolving files.pythonhosted.org (files.pythonhosted.org)... 151.101.29.63
Connecting to files.pythonhosted.org 
(files.pythonhosted.org)|151.101.29.63|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24390482 (23M) [binary/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'

vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd6 100% 
[==========================>]  23.26M  52.7MB/s    in 0.4s

2019-06-20 08:52:50 (52.7 MB/s) - 'vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' saved 
[24390482/24390482]


C:\Users\staff>pip install vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this 
platform.
```

I omit the full [wget link](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/55/e4f0cdf6634def017a98374a6930ffdd65d84b8ddf1c885a08728de5b408/vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) for formatting purposes.
I would prefer to keep the PC without virtual environments and multiple Python versions to avoid mess. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python is 32-bit and vtk only [provides](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/#files) 64-bit builds. Install 64-bit Python and retry.

Comment: This definitely solved the problem! I accidentally installed the 32-bit version. For the sake of my curiosity, did you managed to debug it from the error message I attached or just because there isn't another explanation for that?

Comment: First I looked at the list of distributions and found there are only 64-bit wheels. Then I saw the *"ERROR: vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."* which means either your Python is not 3.7, the OS is not Windows or Python is not 64-bit. Also I know the Python web site shows 32-bit Python for download by default; to download 64-bit you need to find it in the list of downloads. Because of that 32/64-bitness is a frequent problem.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks again for your help.